# Eigenvalue of commutator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The question is
Let $A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ and consider the map $T_{A}: M_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ given by $T_{A}(X)=A X-X A,$ called the commutator of $A$ and $X .$ Show that $T_{A}$ is linear and zero is an eigenvalue of $T_{A}$

I have shown that $T_{A}$ by considering $$T_{A} (X+aY)=A(X+aY)-(X+aY)A = (AX-XA)+a(AY-YA)=T_{A}(X)+aT_{A}(Y)$$

But how to show that zero is an eigen value of $T_{A}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T_A(A)=0$. Hence $0$ is an eigenvalue of $T_A$

Comment: You would need a different (though trivial) argument for the case $A = 0$.

Comment: But when $A=0$, $T_A(X)=0$ for every $X$